# What does an import statement with "..." in python mean?

Tags: python

I came across certain source code that mentioned `import ...utils`. What does this mean?

The code was in Python3.

Comment: Means you are importing from the *grandparent* directory, aka the parent's parent directory.

Comment: @kpaul: Relative imports aren't a directory traversal mechanism. Thinking about them in terms of directory traversal produces wrong results for cases like namespace packages, or trying to navigate past the root of the package structure.

Comment: @Selcuk that duplicate question doesn't actually have an answer that mentions triple dots

Comment: @craq Please read the answer carefully: "[...] Two dots means up one package level. **Three dots is up two levels, etc.**"

Comment: right, sorry. That was buried in a wall of text. I missed that when skimming it, and searching for "..." and "ellipse" came up blank